# images in a banner disappear when I use max-width or width: auto

Tags: html, css

I have rotating banner images which I'd like to work (scale to fit) in any screen size.

When I use the following, it works:

```
.banner{
    position:absolute; 
    width: 80%; 
    height: 30%; 
    top:5%; 
    left:20%;  
    background:#FFF; 
    border:hidden;
}
```

However, when I try to change the width to for example 40%, the images truncate rather than scale down.

When I tried to use, for example, max-width: 80%, or width: auto, the images totally disappear, even if I use a high `z-index`.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting elements via devtools and try to figure out where is your banner and why it has 0px width?

Comment: can you make a simple jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: Please include sample HTML that demonstrates the problem. We can't tell, for example, if `.banner` is a class on the images, on the images' containers, a container higher up the DOM, etc. A code snippet in the question would work best; please don't put code *just* in an off-site location (jsFiddle, etc.)

Comment: Can anyone help please?! Hi again, I tried adding another div, and the problem came back. #diduknow {position:absolute; width: 20px; height: 30px; top:800%; left:20%; background:#FFF; border:solid';} with <div id="diduknow"> </div> did </div> and this makes the images (in the banner disappear) and the word "did" appear right in the centre of the banner!

Comment: I validated the CSS and found a couple of syntax errors which may have been causing that problem. It's working now. Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting both `width` and `height` on your images, will not care about aspect ratio. Just use `width = 100%`, and leave the `height` related to it (with the technique below).

And then set the container width to whatever you want:

```css
#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 30%;
  background: red;
}

#banner-container {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-container">
    <div id="banner"></div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to show an image inside it, use CSS `background-image` with `background-size: cover`:

```css
#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 30%;
  background: gray;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#banner-container {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-container">
    <div id="banner" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/800/500');"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi again, I tried adding another div, and the problem came back. #diduknow {position:absolute; width: 20px; height: 30px; top:800%; left:20%;  background:#FFF; border:solid';} with <div id="diduknow"> </div>
did
</div> and this makes the images (in the banner disappear) and the word "did" appear right in the centre of the banner!

Comment: @iocnsflow Could you please make a fiddle for that? It's important how you are rotating banners.

Comment: I don't think that's related to it. I just want to be able to position the new div <dive id="diduknow"> under the banner.

Comment: I put the HMTL and the CSS on jsfiddle. What do I do with that fiddle now?